# Consulta mongodb mongoose

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Necesito una ayuda con una consulta en mongoose

Resulta que tengo 2 modelos

Mi modelo de Cliente

```
   const ClienteSchema = Schema({
   rut:{
       type: String,
       require: true
   },
   nombre: {
       type: String,
       require: true
   },
   direccion: {
       type: String,
       require: true
   },
   contacto: {
       type: String,
       require: true
   },
   emailContacto: {
       type: String,
       require: true
   },
   empresa: {
       type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
       ref: 'Empresa'
   }
 })
 module.exports = model('Cliente', ClienteSchema);
```

Mi modelo de Maquinaria

```
   const MaquinariaSchema = Schema({
   serial: {
       type: String,
       require: true,
       unique: true
   },
   modelo: {
       type: String,
   },
   horasTrabajo: {
       type: String
   },
   horasMatenimiento: {
       type: String
   },
   dispositivo: {
       type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
       ref: 'Dispositivo'
   },
   cliente: {
       type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
       ref: 'Cliente'
   },
   empresa: {
       type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
       ref: 'Empresa'
   },
   mantencion: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Mantencion'
   },
   alarmCode: {
       type: String,
       default: '0000'
   }
})
module.exports = model('Maquinaria', MaquinariaSchema);
```

Pregunta es ¿cómo puedo saber la maquinaria a partir del nombre del cliente a atreves de una consulta en mongoose?

agradecería mucho su ayuda ya que llevo más de una semana rompiendome la cabeza tratando de solucionarlo

De antemano muchas gracias y espero haber dado a entender bien

saludos

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado / investigado? Esta es una consulta con referencias muy típica en Mongoose, por lo cual podrías encontrar muchos ejemplos de cómo realizar la consulta. Te sugiero que añadas un [mcve] de lo que has intentado, haciendo clic en [edit]. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente lo he logrado buscando primero al cliente y después recorro el arreglo de resultado y con el _id del cliente voy buscando la maquinaria.

creo que no es un método muy elegante pero funcionó para mí

dejo el código por si a alguien le sirve o tiene alguna sugerencia para mejorar la consulta

```
let result = await Cliente.find({ nombre: regex });
                for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    const element = await Maquinaria.find({ cliente: result[i]._id }).populate('cliente', 'nombre');
                    console.log('element', element);
                    for (let i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
                        var element2 = element[i];
                        f.push(element2);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

También lo puedes hacer con un Aggregate:

```
let result = await Maquinaria.aggregate()
//aca filtras, puede ser, en este caso, por cliente, pero podria ser por marca, o por empresa
.match({cliente: cliente_id }) 
// aca recuperas la info del cliente, es como un populate
.lookup({ from: 'clientes', localField: "cliente", foreignField: '_id', as: 'cliente' }) 
.group({
// agrupas segun el cliente en este caso, pero podria ser por lo que quieras
   _id: "$cliente",  
// creas un arreglo con todas las, en este caso, maquinarias del cliente pero puede ser cualquier otro elemento
   maquinaria: { $push: {
        _id: "$_id", 
        serial: "$serial", 
        modelo: "$modelo",
        horasTrabajo: "$horasTrabajo", 
        horasMantenimiento: "$horasMantenimiento", 
        ...
    })
.unwind('_id') // esto para que tu _id que va a contener los datos del cliente, sea un objeto y no un arreglo
```

Y listo, de esta forma puedes jugar con los valores para hacer consultas realmente poderosas con Mongoose.

Espero le sirva a alguien,